# Angular Universal renders page in wrong way without events

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-universal, server-side-rendering, html-rendering

I migrated this page: https://www.beta.rohub.org to Angular 7  and started to make this page served on Server side rendering by using Angular universal.
The page is rendered, template works, some requests are working, and the page looks normal.

There are some things which are not working.

For Example:

1. click events - are not working totally, there are only buttons not
   working
2. view child
3. Directives
4. NgModel - values from ngmodel are not working after change
5. local storage and cache
6. routing - some components can't initialize after going to example on component for showing research Object.
7. Host Listeners

The Dist folder is generating correctly.

Here is my code. I don't know what is wrong with this all configs.

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ng-universal-demo": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "css"
        }
      },
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.browser.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.browser.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "/assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "favicon.ico",
                "input": "src",
                "output": "/"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/ng2-tree/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": ["./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.min.js"],
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./extra-webpack.config.js",
              "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true,
              "mergeStrategies": {
                "externals": "prepend"
              }
            },
            "serviceWorker": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ng-universal-demo:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ng-universal-demo:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ng-universal-demo:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "/assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "favicon.ico",
                "input": "src",
                "output": "/"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/server",
            "main": "src/main.server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "ng-universal-demo-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e",
      "projectType": "application",
      "cli": {},
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "ng-universal-demo:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {},
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:class": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "spec": false,
      "inlineStyle": true,
      "inlineTemplate": true,
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "css"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "spec": false,
      "prefix": "app"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:guard": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:module": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:service": {
      "spec": false
    }
  }
```

package.json:

```
  "name": "ng-universal-demo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/angular/universal-starter.git"
  },
  "contributors": [],
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "lint": "ng lint ng-universal-demo",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod  --output-hashing=none && ng run ng-universal-demo:server:production",
    "build:prerender": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server && npm run generate:prerender",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
    "compile:server": "tsc -p server.tsconfig.json",
    "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "generate:prerender": "cd dist && node prerender",
    "serve:prerender": "cd dist/browser && http-server",
    "serve:
ssr": "node dist/server"
  },
```

server.ts

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
enableProdMode();

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

const template = readFileSync(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html')).toString();
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require( './dist/server/main');
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));


app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
  }
}
```

webpack.server.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: { server: './server.ts' },
  resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.ts'] },
  target: 'node',
  mode: 'none',
  // this makes sure we include node_modules and other 3rd party libraries
  externals: [/node_modules/],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{ test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }]
  },
  plugins: [
    // Temporary Fix for issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
    // for 'WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression'
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      {}
    )
  ]
};
```

main.server.ts

```
export {AppServerModule} from './app/app.server.module';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

enableProdMode();
```

Comment: What does your app.component.ts selector look like? If I set it to anything except a tag selector, everything will fail as you described.

Comment: <app-root></app-root>

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem.
A firts thing was docuemnt.cookies and window. on my ts code. So I modificated cookies by ngx-cookies-service like this:
commons.service.ts

```
import {CookieService} from 'ngx-cookie-service';

...

constructor(private configurationService: ConfigurationService,
              private cookies: CookieService) {

  }

....

if (name === 'accountType') {
      const cookiesArray = Object.keys(this.cookies.getAll());
      console.log(cookiesArray);
      if (cookiesArray.length >= 1) {
        console.log('COOKIES', cookiesArray, 'END OF COOKIES');
        const objectOfCookies = this.cookies.getAll(),
          arrayOfCookies = Object.keys(objectOfCookies),
          typeIndex = arrayOfCookies.indexOf(name);

        if (typeIndex !== -1) {
          const arrayOfAccounts = ['ORCID', 'GOOGLE', 'EVEREST'];
          for (const currentElement of arrayOfAccounts) {
            if (arrayOfCookies.indexOf(currentElement) !== -1) {
              this.properCookieValue = currentElement;
              break;
            }
          }
        } else {
          this.properCookieValue = null;
        }
      }
    } else {
```

Second thing: Everything with my files was ok, the only thing on server.ts needed a change. 
So server.ts looks like that:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import { join } from 'path';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
enableProdMode();
const domino = require('domino');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');


const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require( './dist/server/main');
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));


const template = readFileSync(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html')).toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(template);
global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

app.use(cookieParser('Your private token'));
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Events are not firing. Can you elaborate on this answer please? What have you changed in the files described above?